# replace 0 with blank spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to show blank '' instead of Zero value of Expression field. If exp is of INT datatype. whenever I try to use(case when exp1 is 0 then '' else exp1 end as exp1)but it still gets 0 as output.any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here.  Could you post the code that you tried?

Comment: You'll probably want to use the `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` keywords.

Comment: I have fields , ids is varchar , but height and weight are interger type. right now I get 0s for height and weight if there is no values(using case statement).  But I want blank in those fields

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `exp` is a numeric type you'll need to convert it to a string using [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Also, I don't believe `exp1 is 0` will work; I think you're looking for `exp1 = 0` instead.

Try something like this this:

```
(case when exp1 = 0 then '' else cast(exp1 as varchar(30)) end) as exp1

(case when exp1 = 0 then '' else convert(varchar(30), exp1) end) as exp1
```

Or using a simple `CASE` expression, like this:

```
(case exp1 when 0 then '' else cast(exp1 as varchar(30)) end) as exp1

(case exp1 when 0 then '' else convert(varchar(30), exp1) end) as exp1
```

Note: The default length for `varchar` and `nvarchar` in `CAST` and `CONVERT` is 30, so `cast(exp1 as varchar)` or `convert(varchar, exp1)` would work as well, but as a matter of practice it's best to specify the lengths of these types whenever you use them.

---

However, if what you'd rather do is convert the value 0 to `null`, it's fairly easy. Just use [`NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx):

```
nullif(exp1, 0) exp1
```

This will return `NULL` if `exp1` evaluates to 0, otherwise it will return the value of `exp1`. When you're inserting this value into a table, make sure the column you are inserting it into is nullable. If you're not familiar with using null, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) on the topic for more information.

Comment: [Please don't be lazy about varchar vs. varchar(n)](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I actually had `varchar(30)` at first but dropped it to make the code more compact and because I thought OP would prefer that. But you're right, it is better to be explicit about those things. Anyway, thanks for the article.

Comment: still showing as 0 in those field. I have source-table where height and weight are in varchar() and destination-table the height and weight are in numeric().                                           I want to insert the source-data into destination. But the problem here is the height and weight field keeps showing up as zero in destination, whenever it is has no value. I just want blank there
id   height   weight
b25    146      162
t41    135      
g89             201

tableB-destination

id   height   weight
b25    146      162
t41    135      0
g89      0       201

Comment: Well you simply can't store an empty string into a numeric column. The only option is to make it `null`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, can that be done. would you please show the code for that.Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I used RegEx

```
{
    cast(trim(
    replace(to_char(value),'0','' )) as int)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the shortest way would be the following:

```
ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF(exp1,0) AS VARCHAR), '')
```